# opengles texture unit behavior

Tags: opengl-es, textures

Newbie questions...Pertains to OpenGLES 2.0 + Android

1)Are uploaded textures and states preserved across drawarrays calls ?
When we upload a texture using glTexImage2D for an active Texture5 (say), will it still be there even if another GL context uses Texture5 and uploads another texture to it ? 
If so, it would save me quite a bit of ordeal for operations in between two video frames.

2) If I bind textureobjectA to active Texture5 and upload texture will it get overwritten if I bind textureobjectB to active Texture5 and upload some other data to it ?

3) Is activating Texture5 equivalent to activating hardware unit for texture or is it just a state activation ? I ask this because, if another context activates the same unit there could be a problem, which leads me to think it is only a state activation. 
If so how much memory is available for all the contexts and texture uploads done by them in the GPU ?

appreciate any response

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the term `active Texture` is concerning. You do not upload textures to texture units, you bind texture objects to them. You upload texture image data to texture objects.

Now, if you are asking whether the texture bound to texture image unit 5 in one context affects another, the answer is absolutely not. Even with context resource sharing, each context has its own discrete set of texture image units (because each context has its own state machine).

And "activating" a texture unit is merely a consequence of OpenGL's questionable design where you have to use a selector function to indicate which object the next command(s) apply to. It does nothing beyond telling `glTexImage2D (...)`, for instance, that it applies to the 2D texture currently bound to the *active* texture image unit.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. Can we infer that texture objects and texture data are not linked with the maximum texture samplers or texture hardware units in GPU and that they merely reflect the maximum textures units(TEXTURE0-31 or 63) made available to each program. In simple terms I may be able to use only a max of 64 texture samplers(or lesser number from query) in the program.

Comment: OpenGL guarantees you 16 texture units per-shader stage. You are limited to 16 texture lookups in the vertex shader, 16 in the fragment, 16 in geometry. That makes 48 texture units in GL3, and because GL4 added 2 new stages (tessellation control / evaluation) it was raised to 80. For all intents and purposes, you can have 80 different textures bound in GL4, but you can only ever use a subset of 16 of them in a single shader stage.

Comment: Sorry, just realized this was a discussion about OpenGL ES. Ignore a few of the things I said ;) GL ES only requires 8 texture units, does not have geometry or tessellation shaders, and the ability to sample from vertex shaders is optional. I would suggest you look into `GL_MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS` and `GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_UNITS` for a more thorough discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Andon. The 8 texture units are per program right? So I could technically chain multiple programs until (VRAM ?) memory limits me from creating more texture objects and programs.

Comment: The 8 texture units (note, this is only a minimum requirement - you may have more) are a global state, independent of any GLSL program. You can only have 8 textures **bound** *total* at any given time. As for the number of texture objects, there is no limitation there other than RAM to store the images. On many embedded devices VRAM and system RAM are the same thing, but on discrete GPUs you can sometimes exceed VRAM and store unused textures in system memory. This can become a bottleneck though, similar to page/swap file thrashing when an operating system is low on system memory.

Comment: On RAM VRAM being same in embedded devices.. is this the case in typical smartphones ? If so, a DMA transfer is needed every time a program using a texture is run. Isnt it more efficient to cache textures within GPU (assuming GPU has a large memory cache) ? If so, is it better to combine stuff into one shader than using multiple shaders to prevent cache invalidation whenever program is switched ?

Comment: No, they literally share the same memory bus on devices that use system memory as VRAM, DMA does not come into play at all because the CPU is not necessary for the GPU to acccess the shared memory. And the "texture cache" is ridiculously small on GPUs, it is usually not large enough to store an entire texture, just large enough to cache samples for parallel executions of a shader. Embedded GPUs may still have dedicated texture caches, but modern GPUs have a general cache architecture similar to CPUs (L1/shared L2) for compute units (on the order of about 16-32/64-128 KiB respectively).